# `inner` vs `sub` for function name?

Tags: naming-conventions

I use class `Page` that handles some information. But I don't know what to choose for the name of the method: `getInnerPage($uname)` or `getSubPage($uname)`

The base page may look like this: `http://abc.net/base`

And the inner or sub: `http://abc.net/base/sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We often use `sub`, which represents a hierarchical view, whilst `inner` would be more appropriated for containers' content.

but I don't know if there really are conventions for this